# Why doesn't react.component function definition contain a reference to .state property?

Tags: reactjs

I feel like this is a stupid question, and reflects my limited understanding of javascript.

In the [source code for react](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js) the definition of `function Component` makes no reference to `state` which is a core concept of react.

1. Is this because `react.component` doesn't have a `state` property, and
   only child extensions of `react.component` have a `state` property if defined locally by the user?
2. Or is `state` defined somewhere else (in the source code?) and I'm
   totally missing it?

I've looked through a number of blogs, tutorials, and explanations of `state` and cannot find an answer to this question.

Comment: it's defined somewhere else. Take a look at implementation of `setState` method

Answer (score 0):

Yoy have to through Stateful vs. Stateless Functional Components in React, here is a link

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/stateful-vs-stateless-functional-components-in-react--cms-29541

Answer (score 0):

The `setState` method is added to the prototype of`Component` later in the file you linked. `setState` (as the name suggests) is used within your component to set the state and then trigger the `render` process. It's down to the implementation of your component to define what the state shape is the component constructor. e.g.:

```
constructor() { 
    this.state = {
       foo: 0
    }
}
```

This is how `setState` is defined (on the `Component` prototype):

```
Component.prototype.setState = function(partialState, callback) {
  invariant(
    typeof partialState === 'object' ||
      typeof partialState === 'function' ||
      partialState == null,
    'setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a ' +
      'function which returns an object of state variables.',
  );
  this.updater.enqueueSetState(this, partialState, callback, 'setState');
};
```

The `updater` object is injected into the component during the mounting phase (implementation of the updater is dependent on platform);

```
function Component(props, context, updater)
```

So when you call `setState` `enqueueSetState` is called on the `updater`.

Later on, through various functions (`flushBatchedUpdates`, `updateComponent`) execution ends up in `_processPendingState` - in this function it dequeues pending state changes and assigns them to your component state.

`_processPendingState` is expecting a property called `state` on your component and this is what gets used when the state is finally updated.

Implementation of `_processPendingState` is here:

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v0.14.7/src/renderers/shared/reconciler/ReactCompositeComponent.js#L631-L658

Detailed write-up of internals of react here:

https://bogdan-lyashenko.github.io/Under-the-hood-ReactJS/